# Xamarin Math with different tabs?

Tags: c#, ios, xcode, xamarin

I have to make a deathcalc for class and this is what i have so far.

Now to problem is that i have to do math. So if the person switches one of the switches it adds or subtracts from the total.

right now i need to do that math part. Im not 100% positive on how to do math across different tabs. If someone could help me that would be great.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tP7FY.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/asw8L.jpg

Comment: Maybe create an object to hold the responses. Call it Survey or something. Then pass that into all your ViewControllers. Then have a function in your Survey object that does the math.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare properties you can access from anywhere in your app.

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL doYouEatWell;
// etc.

@end
```

FoodViewController:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "FoodViewController.h"

- (void)switchChanged:(UISwitch *)theSwitch
{
    if (theSwitch == self.doYouEatWellSwitch)
    {
        ((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).doYouEatWell = self.doYouEatWellSwitch.on)
    }
}
```

TotalViewController:

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "TotalViewController.h"

if (((AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]).doYouEatWell == YES)
{
    // User has said that they eat well.
}
```

Comment: I have not learned how to do this yet. What we did in class was crated a new .cs and did public decimal FoodToal {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public decimal HealthTotal {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public decimal GetTotal () {
   return FoodToal + HealthTotal;
  }

Comment: All the code you need I have provided basically. What do you need help with additionally?

Comment: Im very new to this but i dont quite understand where i put it. and what its used for.

Comment: Do you have 4 view controller's for your tab bar based app?

Comment: Great, that's a very logical setup. Do you have an IBAction for your UISwitch value changed for each view controller?

Comment: @troop231 is giving you examples written in Obj-C, not C#.  I think that is where the confusion is coming from.  Conceptually it will work the same in Xamarin, but the syntax will be different.

Comment: Thanks, I created a new cs called .cs and made diffrent properties and that seems to be working just fine. but i ran into a new issue so thanks guys! :)